# flutter export apk not installed to any device

Tags: android, flutter

I get apk debug output flutter in Android Studio, but it doesn't install on any device. But it runs in Android Studio on my device. What is the problem?
The previous version is on Google Play. I upgraded the code version and the application version, but it does not install on any device.

```
I even created a new project and got apk debug output. Again, it won't install on any device
```

Unfortunately, I tried all the cases, but it didn't work
`flutter.versionCode=2 flutter.versionName=2.0.0 flutter.minSdkVersion = 19 flutter.targetSdkVersion = 30`
my version android device 12

```
android 7 installed android 12 not installed
```

Comment: open android module in new window and generate APK it's work fine.

Comment: I did this, it does not install again

Comment: You need to uninstall old app from your device and then try to install new APK.

Comment: create release build for testing purpose also if you want to upload app on play store you need to create sign apk using keystore and alias.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried all the cases, but it didn't work
`flutter.versionCode=2
flutter.versionName=2.0.0
flutter.minSdkVersion = 19
flutter.targetSdkVersion = 30`
my version android device 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason could be that you're building playstore signed apk and trying to install it in your phone directly which won't work.

In your android/app/build.gradle, make sure you have the following code:

```
buildTypes {
....
   release {
       ....
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug 
       // change it to signingConfigs.release when building bundle for playstore
   }

}
```

Now build apk using `flutter build apk` and in your build > app > outputs > flutter apk > app-release.apk should work now

Comment: I also executed this command, but unfortunately, it was still not installed on the device
my oriject link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C2GtyPxxC0gknDrgH85H1Exl0AlY8bpf/view?usp=share_link

Comment: android 7 installed android 12 not installed

Comment: App not working on android 12 is a separate issue, you can refer to this for that purpose.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897658/flutter-app-not-installable-from-google-store-for-android-12-despite-being-set-t

Comment: I did all these things but it still won't install